# CheckBox state change when scrolling in listView

Tags: android, listview

I'm very mixed up that before I can save state of CheckBoxs in ListView When Scrolling But now dosn't save! I saw many Solutions but I don't see any mistake in my Adapter Class. Please review it and inform me where of code should be changed!

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    protected ArrayList listData;
    protected LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    private SharedPreferences sp;


    private Editor editor;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList listData) {
        this.listData = listData;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        sp=context.getSharedPreferences("sp", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor=sp.edit();

    }

    public CustomListAdapter(OnClickListener onClickListener,
            ArrayList image_details) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public void setListData(ArrayList listdata){
        this.listData=listdata;
    }

    public void remove(int i){
        listData.remove(i);

    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.cb_mark=(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_search_mark);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final Aye aye = (Aye)listData.get(position);    
        aye.setMarked(sp.getBoolean("CheckValue"+position, false));
        holder.cb_mark.setChecked(aye.isMarked());


        holder.cb_mark.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
                aye.setMarked(arg1);
                editor.putBoolean("CheckValue"+position, arg1);
                editor.commit();
                Log.i("CheckValue"+position, sp.getBoolean("CheckValue"+position, false)+"");

            }
        });



        holder.cb_mark.setChecked(aye.isMarked());




        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {

        CheckBox cb_mark;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably problem occur due to wrong `position` value on `onCheckedChanged`. try is as by saving current item position using `setTag` method then use `getTag` inside `onCheckedChanged` to get position :

```
aye.setMarked(sp.getBoolean("CheckValue"+position, false));
holder.cb_mark.setChecked(aye.isMarked());
holder.cb_mark.setTag(position); //<< store position of view

holder.cb_mark.setOnCheckedChangeListener(....{

 @Override
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
   aye.setMarked(arg1);
   int pos=Integer.parseInt(arg0.getTag().toString());  
   editor.putBoolean("CheckValue"+pos, arg1);
   editor.commit();

  }
});
```

Comment: position value is correct, I used Log.i() in OnCheckedChaned method that when I click checkbox first item shows in LogCat "CheckValue0 true" after Scrolling show in LogCat "CheckValue0 false"

Comment: @user3885462 : if possible can you try using my suggestion?

Comment: I'm trying now and will inform you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue,
Just simple solution here, If you implemented adapter class correctly.

```
 @Override
  public int getViewTypeCount() {
      if(getCount() < 1)
            return 1;
      return getCount();
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {

   return position;
  }
```